# Minimum and maximum values from different mysql tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: TableA and TableB. Both have "dates" and "rates" fields. I want to have minimum rates of TableA and their dates; and maximum rates of TableB and their dates. Also, I like to list them for each month and year.

I use the query below to get minimum and maximum rates from **one table**.  But I could not figure  out how to get minimum rates from TableA maximum rates from TableB.

```
SELECT
MIN(rate) AS minRate,
(SELECT date FROM TableA WHERE rate = min(t2.rate) and  month(date) = month(t2.date) and     year(date) = year(t2.date) limit 1 ) as minDate,
MONTHNAME(date) as MN, YEAR(date) as YN,
MAX(rate) AS maxRate,
(SELECT date FROM TableAs  WHERE rate = max(t2.rate) and  month(date) = month(t2.date)  and year(date) = year(t2.date) limit 1) as maxDate
FROM TableA  t2
GROUP BY YEAR(date) , MONTH(date)";
```

**EDIT 1:** I ended up with this.

```
SELECT a.MinYear AS Year, a.MinMonth AS Month, a.MinRate, b.MaxRate, a.MinDate, b.MaxDate
FROM (SELECT YEAR(date) AS MinYear, MONTH(date) AS MinMonth, MIN(rate) AS MinRate, 
    (SELECT date FROM $TableA  WHERE rate = MIN(t2.rate) AND YEAR(date) =    YEAR(t2.date) AND  MONTH(date) = MONTH(t2.date) limit 1) AS MinDate
        FROM $TableA t2
        GROUP BY MinYear, MinMonth
   ) AS a   
JOIN (SELECT YEAR(date) AS MaxYear, MONTH(date) AS MaxMonth, MAX(rate) AS MaxRate, 
    (SELECT date FROM $TableB  WHERE rate = MAX(t3.rate) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(t3.date) AND  MONTH(date) = MONTH(t3.date) limit 1) AS MaxDate
        FROM $TableB t3
        GROUP BY MaxYear, MaxMonth
   ) AS b
ON a.MinYear = b.MaxYear AND a.MinMonth = b.MaxMonth
ORDER BY Year, Month
```

**EDIT 2**
Jonathan Leffler's query (with minor changes after testing) performs better:

```
SELECT a.MinYear AS Year, a.MinMonth AS Month, a.MinDate, a.MinRate, b.MaxDate, b.MaxRate

FROM (SELECT n.MinYear, n.MinMonth, a.Date AS MinDate, n.MinRate
      FROM $TableA AS a
      JOIN (SELECT YEAR(date) AS MinYear, MONTH(date) AS MinMonth, MIN(rate) AS MinRate
             FROM $TableA
             GROUP BY MinYear, MinMonth
           ) AS n
        ON a.Rate = n.MinRate AND YEAR(a.Date) = n.MinYear AND MONTH(a.Date) = n.MinMonth
   ) AS a

 JOIN (SELECT x.MaxYear, x.MaxMonth, b.Date AS MaxDate, x.MaxRate
      FROM $TableB AS b

        JOIN (SELECT YEAR(date) AS MaxYear, MONTH(date) AS MaxMonth, MAX(rate) AS MaxRate
             FROM $TableB
             GROUP BY MaxYear, MaxMonth
           ) AS x
        ON b.Rate = x.MaxRate AND YEAR(b.Date) = x.MaxYear AND MONTH(b.Date) = x.MaxMonth
   ) AS b
ON a.MinYear = b.MaxYear AND a.MinMonth = b.MaxMonth
ORDER BY Year, Month";
```

Comment: what columns should be used to connect rows from the two tables? do you literally want just one row?

Comment: @Bohemian: I want to have minimum value of each month from TableA and  maximum value of each month from TableB

Comment: If you can get the query above to work for one table, couldn't you just create 2 queries that pull the information you want and then do an inner join on the month and year? E.g., Select * from (select * from tablea) as t1 inner join (select * from tableb) as t2 on t1.year(date) = t2.year(date) AND t1.month(date) = t2.month(date)

Comment: @gangreen: Could you add your comment as an answer? Do you mean "select inside select"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Original answer

You need to create two result sets, one from tableA, one from TableB, and then join them.  As with any complex SQL query, I build the result up in parts.  First, we need the minimum rate for each month from TableA:

```
SELECT YEAR(date) AS MinYear, MONTH(date) AS MinMonth, MIN(rate) AS MinRate
  FROM TableA
 GROUP BY MinYear, MinMonth;
```

The analogous query for maximum rates from TableB is:

```
SELECT YEAR(date) AS MaxYear, MONTH(date) AS MaxMonth, MAX(rate) AS MaxRate
  FROM TableB
 GROUP BY MaxYear, MaxMonth;
```

Now you need to join these two results on year and month columns:

```
SELECT a.MinYear AS Year, a.MinMonth AS Month, a.MinRate, b.MaxRate
  FROM (SELECT YEAR(date) AS MinYear, MONTH(date) AS MinMonth, MIN(rate) AS MinRate
          FROM TableA
         GROUP BY MinYear, MinMonth
       ) AS a
  JOIN (SELECT YEAR(date) AS MaxYear, MONTH(date) AS MaxMonth, MAX(rate) AS MaxRate
          FROM TableB
         GROUP BY MaxYear, MaxMonth
       ) AS b
    ON a.MinYear = b.MaxYear AND a.MinMonth = b.MaxMonth
 ORDER BY Year, Month;
```

---

#### Extension to manage missing data

If you have to worry about missing data from either TableA or TableB, then life is a bit more complex.  You then really need a FULL OUTER JOIN, but some DBMS do not offer that.  If you have to worry about some months being unrepresented in both tables, then you need to generate a table which specifies the dates (month and year) that you're interested in, and then you can LEFT OUTER JOIN that with each of the two expressions above.

```
SELECT c.RefYear AS Year, c.RefMonth AS Month, a.MinRate, b.MaxRate
  FROM MonthYearTable AS c
  LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT YEAR(date) AS MinYear, MONTH(date) AS MinMonth, MIN(rate) AS MinRate
          FROM TableA
         GROUP BY MinYear, MinMonth
       ) AS a
    ON c.RefYear = a.MinYear AND c.RefMonth = a.MinMonth
  LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT YEAR(date) AS MaxYear, MONTH(date) AS MaxMonth, MAX(rate) AS MaxRate
          FROM TableB
         GROUP BY MaxYear, MaxMonth
       ) AS b
    ON c.RefYear = b.MaxYear AND c.RefMonth = b.MaxMonth
 ORDER BY Year, Month;
```

If need be, you can specify the range of dates you are interested in from the MonthYearTable.

---

#### Finding the dates when the extremum rates occurred

If, as suggested in the comments, the answer should include the exact date(s) within each month when the maximum or minimum rate occurred, then the 'find the extremum' sub-queries are more complex:

```
SELECT n.MinYear, n.MinMonth, a.Date AS MinDate, n.MinRate
  FROM TableA AS a
  JOIN (SELECT YEAR(date) AS MinYear, MONTH(date) AS MinMonth, MIN(rate) AS MinRate
          FROM TableA
         GROUP BY MinYear, MinMonth
       ) AS n
    ON a.Rate = n.MinRate AND YEAR(a.Date) = n.MinYear AND MONTH(a.Date) = n.MinMonth
```

Similarly for the query against TableB:

```
SELECT x.MaxYear, x.MaxMonth, b.Date AS MaxDate, x.MaxRate
  FROM TableB AS b
  JOIN (SELECT YEAR(date) AS MaxYear, MONTH(date) AS MaxMonth, MAX(rate) AS MaxRate
          FROM TableB
         GROUP BY MaxYear, MaxMonth
       ) AS x
    ON b.Rate = x.MinRate AND YEAR(b.Date) = x.MaxYear AND MONTH(b.Date) = x.MaxMonth
```

Combining these leads to the query:

```
SELECT a.MinYear AS Year, a.MinMonth AS Month, a.MinDate, a.MinRate, b.MinDate, b.MaxRate
  FROM (SELECT n.MinYear, n.MinMonth, a.Date AS MinDate, n.MinRate
          FROM TableA AS a
          JOIN (SELECT YEAR(date) AS MinYear, MONTH(date) AS MinMonth, MIN(rate) AS MinRate
                  FROM TableA
                 GROUP BY MinYear, MinMonth
               ) AS n
            ON a.Rate = n.MinRate AND YEAR(a.Date) = n.MinYear AND MONTH(a.Date) = n.MinMonth
       ) AS a
  JOIN (SELECT x.MaxYear, x.MaxMonth, b.Date AS MaxDate, x.MaxRate
          FROM TableB AS b
          JOIN (SELECT YEAR(date) AS MaxYear, MONTH(date) AS MaxMonth, MAX(rate) AS MaxRate
                  FROM TableB
                 GROUP BY MaxYear, MaxMonth
               ) AS x
            ON b.Rate = x.MinRate AND YEAR(b.Date) = x.MaxYear AND MONTH(b.Date) = x.MaxMonth
       ) AS a
    ON a.MinYear = b.MaxYear AND a.MinMonth = b.MaxMonth
 ORDER BY Year, Month;
```

Note that if the same minimum rate is reported on three different days in a given month, this will have three lines of output for that month, one for each of those days.  In fact, if there are also two days on which the maximum rate occurred, then there'll be *six* lines of output for that month.  If this is not what's required, then you can do an appropriate aggregate (meaning MIN or MAX, most likely) on the dates within the month:

```
SELECT n.MinYear, n.MinMonth, MAX(a.Date) AS MinDate, n.MinRate
  FROM TableA AS a
  JOIN (SELECT YEAR(date) AS MinYear, MONTH(date) AS MinMonth, MIN(rate) AS MinRate
          FROM TableA
         GROUP BY MinYear, MinMonth
       ) AS n
    ON a.Rate = n.MinRate AND YEAR(a.Date) = n.MinYear AND MONTH(a.Date) = n.MinMonth
 GROUP BY n.MinYear, n.MinMonth, n.MinRate
```

And then combine this expression into the 'final' (next) version of the main query:

```
SELECT a.MinYear AS Year, a.MinMonth AS Month, a.MinDate, a.MinRate, b.MinDate, b.MaxRate
  FROM (SELECT n.MinYear, n.MinMonth, MAX(a.Date) AS MinDate, n.MinRate
          FROM TableA AS a
          JOIN (SELECT YEAR(date) AS MinYear, MONTH(date) AS MinMonth, MIN(rate) AS MinRate
                  FROM TableA
                 GROUP BY MinYear, MinMonth
               ) AS n
            ON a.Rate = n.MinRate AND YEAR(a.Date) = n.MinYear AND MONTH(a.Date) = n.MinMonth
         GROUP BY x.MaxYear, x.MaxMonth, x.MaxRate
       ) AS a
  JOIN (SELECT x.MaxYear, x.MaxMonth, MAX(b.Date) AS MaxDate, x.MaxRate
          FROM TableB AS b
          JOIN (SELECT YEAR(date) AS MaxYear, MONTH(date) AS MaxMonth, MAX(rate) AS MaxRate
                  FROM TableB
                 GROUP BY MaxYear, MaxMonth
               ) AS x
            ON b.Rate = x.MinRate AND YEAR(b.Date) = x.MaxYear AND MONTH(b.Date) = x.MaxMonth
         GROUP BY n.MinYear, n.MinMonth, n.MinRate
       ) AS a
    ON a.MinYear = b.MaxYear AND a.MinMonth = b.MaxMonth
 ORDER BY Year, Month;
```

I'd hate to try to write that final query out in one go.  But by building it up in stages, I'm moderately confident, even without submitting it to a DBMS, that it is close to accurate.  If I was testing it, I might go straight for the final query, but if there was a problem with it, then I'd test the component queries, working with one sub-query at a time until the parts were producing the correct results and then combining the total query.

---

#### Extension to handle date ranges and missing data again

In the comments, the MonthYearTable caused minor confusion.  As noted in my response in the comments, the issue is that if you have data in tables A and B for January and March but for some peculiar reason there is no data for February, then the 'final' query will not show anything for February.  If you want to see explicitly the (absence of) values for February, the MonthYearTable
can contain rows such as:

```
Year    Month
2011    1
2011    2
2011    3
```

And you can select the months to be reported on from there, and do a LEFT OUTER JOIN with the extremum queries in the final table.  That way, even though there's no data in TableA or TableB for February (2011-02), the will be a result row showing that.  And, supposing you actually had data in YearMonthTable for every month from January 2009 to December 2012, but you wanted the report to cover the period from July 2009 to June 2011, you'd need to specify the filter condition on MonthYearTable (and you'd probably also do it on TableA and TableB because the optimizer is unlikely to infer the sub-range for you).

```
SELECT c.RefYear AS Year, c.RefMonth AS Month, a.MinDate, a.MinRate, b.MaxDate, b.MaxRate
  FROM MonthYearTable AS c
  LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT n.MinYear, n.MinMonth, MAX(a.Date) AS MinDate, n.MinRate
          FROM TableA AS a
          JOIN (SELECT YEAR(m.date) AS MinYear, MONTH(m.date) AS MinMonth, MIN(m.rate) AS MinRate
                  FROM TableA AS m
                 WHERE m.date BETWEEN DATE '2009-07-01' AND DATE '2011-06-30'
                 GROUP BY MinYear, MinMonth
               ) AS n
            ON a.Rate = n.MinRate AND YEAR(a.Date) = n.MinYear AND MONTH(a.Date) = n.MinMonth
         GROUP BY x.MaxYear, x.MaxMonth, x.MaxRate
       ) AS a
  JOIN (SELECT x.MaxYear, x.MaxMonth, MAX(b.Date) AS MaxDate, x.MaxRate
          FROM TableB AS b
          JOIN (SELECT YEAR(m.date) AS MaxYear, MONTH(m.date) AS MaxMonth, MAX(m.rate) AS MaxRate
                  FROM TableB AS m
                 WHERE m.date BETWEEN DATE '2009-07-01' AND DATE '2011-06-30'
                 GROUP BY MaxYear, MaxMonth
               ) AS x
            ON b.Rate = x.MinRate AND YEAR(b.Date) = x.MaxYear AND MONTH(b.Date) = x.MaxMonth
         GROUP BY n.MinYear, n.MinMonth, n.MinRate
       ) AS a
    ON a.MinYear = b.MaxYear AND a.MinMonth = b.MaxMonth
 WHERE ((c.RefYear = 2009 AND c.RefMonth >= 7) OR (c.RefYear > 2009))
   AND ((c.RefYear = 2011 AND c.RefMonth <= 6) OR (c.RefYear < 2011))
 ORDER BY Year, Month;
```

You could apply more tweaks to the query, especially adding the date range filter in more places.  You could consider using an expression such as:

```
WHERE (c.RefYear * 100 + c.RefMonth) BETWEEN 200907 AND 201106
```

to express the date range in the MonthYearTable.  (For this purpose, the DATETIME YEAR TO MONTH type that Informix supports is ideal; the MonthYearTable need only contain a single column containing a value of that type.)

And so the story continues...you can play endlessly with the query, but as long as you build it up in pieces and apply the extra criteria systematically, you'll be able to manage.  Doing it *ad hoc* and trying for a big bang query (and not laying the queries out systematically) will just lead to confusion and disaster.

---

#### Analyzing the updated query in the question

Correlated sub-queries in the select-list, albeit in the select-list of a sub-query in the FROM clause of a main query; and LIMIT clauses too.  Ouch!  I tend to avoid writing a sub-query in the select-list when possible; they hurt my brain even more than the queries in the style I do write.  OTOH, carefully handled, they sometimes do the necessary job.

When reformatted in my style, the revised query looks like:

```
SELECT a.MinYear AS Year, a.MinMonth AS Month, a.MinRate, b.MaxRate, a.MinDate, b.MaxDate
  FROM (SELECT YEAR(date) AS MinYear, MONTH(date) AS MinMonth, MIN(rate) AS MinRate, 
               (SELECT date
                  FROM $TableA
                 WHERE rate = MIN(t2.rate)
                   AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(t2.date) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(t2.date)
                 LIMIT 1
               ) AS MinDate
          FROM $TableA t2
         GROUP BY MinYear, MinMonth
        ) AS a   
  JOIN (SELECT YEAR(date) AS MaxYear, MONTH(date) AS MaxMonth, MAX(rate) AS MaxRate, 
               (SELECT date
                  FROM $TableB
                 WHERE rate = MAX(t3.rate)
                   AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(t3.date) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(t3.date)
                  LIMIT 1
               ) AS MaxDate
          FROM $TableB t3
         GROUP BY MaxYear, MaxMonth
        ) AS b
     ON a.MinYear = b.MaxYear AND a.MinMonth = b.MaxMonth
  ORDER BY Year, Month;
```

That might work, but I'm not going to pontificate on that.  I will say that most DBMS I'm familiar with would probably baulk on the `MAX(t3.rate)` and `MIN(t2.rate)` terms.  I would not trust the query without experimentation.  I also tend not to trust `LIMIT 1`, doubly not when there's no ordering criterion.  It is at the whim of the DBMS which row is returned if there's more than one row that the LIMIT could be applied to, and non-deterministic queries are generally a bad idea.

So, while that might work, it is not what I'd ever use - even assuming that my DBMS accepted it.  Actually, it's easier than that for me; the way I think about queries would never come up with that one design, so there is essentially no risk of me formulating the query like that.  Whether that's good or not is a separate discussion.

Comment: Something close to this is what I was getting at in my comment on the question. @Jonathan - I think the OP also wants to see the exact date that the minimum and maximum occur on too.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: I could not figure out why and/or how "MonthYearTable" will be used.

Comment: If you need the exact date(s) on which the maximum or minimum (extremum) occurs, then you have to find the extremum value within the month, and then find the entry or entries that satisfied that.  It is fiddly rather than incredibly difficult.

Comment: As to the MonthYearTable, suppose you want to see results for January, February and March, but there us no data for February for some reason.  With the MonthYearTable, you can specify that each of the months should be reported, and empty data (nulls) will be shown for February.  Without the MonthYearTable, you'd only see an entry for January and another for March.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Your query gives the result I want.  But how can I get the "exact date". For example, a minimum value  and a maximum value occurred for February  should be displayed 2012-02-15 1.567 2012 02 29 2.432

Comment: @mustafa: Se the (major) revision.  More fiddly than truly difficult, once you've done it the first few dozen times.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: While you are updating your answer, I tried something. Please see my edit. Is that Ok?   I will study on your "revision" now.

Answer (score 0):

why can't you just use TableB in select statement

Comment: The query in my question is for getting max and min rates from one table. If I put TableB into the second select statement I can get max rate from TableB but this time I can not get dates.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understood what you need but I think you need minimum rates from tableA for each year-month and maximum rates from tableB for each year-month.

So, assuming that each tableA and tableB has 2 columns "rate" and "date", the below queries should work:

For retrieving minimum values from tableA per year-month:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y%m') AS `yearmonth`, MIN(rate) AS `minrate`
FROM `tableA`
GROUP BY `yearmonth`;
```

For retrieving maximum values from tableB per year-month:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y%m') AS `yearmonth`, MAX(rate) AS `maxrate`
FROM `tableB`
GROUP BY `yearmonth`;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes I want to get rates: min rates from tableA and max rates from TableB. But they should be in one query and also I want to get dates min and max occured on.

Comment: @mustafa, perhaps you did not run the queries. They do give you the dates when min and max occurred on. Any specific reason why you need it to be in the single query? Well, you may put a UNION ALL between the 2 queries to make them a single query